# how to send an authentication token through ajax ? node.js

Tags: node.js, ajax, authentication, token

I used postman to test my login, registration requests. it does work by sending the token as a `res.send('x-auth',token)`. but when I tried to use ajax to submit user input to the database the token get sent but remains `undefined` when called by `req.header('x-auth')`. that causes my app to return `401 (unauthorized)` when a user tries to `GET` or `POST` data.

My authentication file I use to verify user authority to display data.

```
const {User} = require('.././models/users-Model');

var authenticate = function(req, res, next){
  var token = req.header('x-auth');
  console.log(token);
  User.findByToken(token).then(function(user){
    if(!user){
      return Promise.reject();
    }
    req.user = user;
    req.token = token;
    next();
  }).catch(function(e){
    res.status(401).send();
  });
}

module.exports = {authenticate};
```

in app.js

```
function userLogin(req, res){
  var body = _.pick(req.body, ["email", "password"]);

  User.findByCredentials(body.email, body.password).then(function(user){
    return user.generateAuthToken().then(function(token){
      res.header('x-auth', token).send(user);
    });
  }).catch(function(e){
    res.status(400).send();
  });
}
app.post('/users/login', userLogin);

function listPost(req, res){
  var Data = new budgetCalculator({
    _creator:req.user._id,
    _id: req.body._id,
    firstItem: req.body.firstItem,
    firstPrice: req.body.firstPrice,
    secondItem: req.body.secondItem,
    secondPrice: req.body.secondPrice,
    thirdItem: req.body.thirdItem,
    thirdPrice: req.body.thirdPrice,
    tBudget: req.body.tBudget
  });
  Data.save().then(function(Data){
    res.send(Data);
  }).catch(function(e){
    res.send(e)
  });
}

app.post('/' , authenticate, listPost);
```

the `AJAX GET` request for listing the posts.

```
// GET all notes from database
$(function (){
  $("#showAll").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url:'/budget',
      type:'get',
      dataType: 'html',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      data: JSON.stringify(),
      success: function(Data){
          $("#DisplayNotes").text(Data);
          $('#DisplayNotes').css({
            display: 'inline-block'
          });
      },
      error: function(err, status, xhr){
        $("#DisplayNotes").addClass('alert-danger').removeClass('alert-success');
        $("#DisplayNotes").text('ERROR!');
        $('#DisplayNotes').css({
          display: 'inline-block'
        });
        $("#DisplayNotes").fadeOut(3000, function() { $(this).css({display: 'none'});
        $("#DisplayNotes").addClass('alert-success').removeClass('alert-danger');
      });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

the `AJAX POST` request for login form submission.

```
$(function(){
  $('.form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url:'/users/login',
      type:'post',
      dataType:'json',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      data: JSON.stringify({
        email: $('input[type="email"]').val(),
        password: $('input[type="password"]').val()
      }),
      success: function(doc){
        window.location = "/app";
      },
      error: function(err, status, xhr){
        console.log(err);
        $('#sucess').text(err);
      }
    });
  })
});
```

Comment: Please work on your capitalization and grammar. It really helps those who try to answer your question.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show us the code where you are doing the AJAX call `GET` to list the posts? Most probably you are not setting the headers in the ajax settings i.e. `$.ajax({
                headers: {
                    'x-auth': your_web_token_here
                },
                type: 'GET',
                url: `/posts`,
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: 'json', ...`

Comment: i think you're right about not setting the headers.. but how to set it dynamically ? i've got no idea, as its my first time trying to wire a frontend.

Comment: In your `User.findByCredentials` function you can send the token in the response body and on the client side, you would store the token in HTML5 `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` (Web Storage):  `success: function(doc) {
    window.sessionStorage.accessToken = doc.token;
}` and then get the `accessToken` from `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` when you set the headers.

Comment: do you have any guide about storing them in sessionStorage? i have seen some but they're not detailed at all.